# using mixed effect logistic regression properly

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am new to data analysis and now working on a Mixed Effects Logistic Regression Model.Currently I have a data frame (`model_data`) that looks like the following:

```
Vehicle_id    entry_time         exit_time          last_veh_time  vehicle_type 
__________     ___________       __________        ____________    ____________ 
   1        2017-01-31 00:00:00  2017-01-31 00:00:00    300         4 wheel   
status
_______
  0
```

Likewise, I have information(nearly a million rows) on all vehicles entering a place and exiting the same place. `status` can be either 1 or 0 for all of these. `last_veh_time` is the last vehicle passed the same place before how much time. I want to know the probability of a getting status 0 for a vehicle based on `entry_time` and `last_veh_time`. So here my response is status and which will be my dependent variable?Is it entry_time and  last_veh_time?Any help is appreciated